# How can I change the font in latex Beamer (using LuaLatex) to Calibri font?

Tags: beamer, luatex

When trying to reproduce a slide in Powerpoint (with font Calibri) to Latex beamer, I've noticed that the font used by Latex beamer "takes more space": it uses a larger space between words and the letters also look like wider.
Here is the Powerpoint output:
[image: Powerpoint]

And here is the latex beamer output (the text in the third box needs two lines here, at the font takes more space):
[image: Latex beamer]

I tried to change the font in latex to Calibri in order to use a font that takes less horizontal space (see my code below, the theme used can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/579082/how-to-center-a-tikz-picture-in-a-latex-beamer-page)), compiling it with LuaLatex (as recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/96993/how-to-use-the-calibri-font)), but it does not seem to change anything in the output. What am I doing wrong?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{theme1}

% packages

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref} % allows clickable urls
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings} % show code
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Calibri}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{snakes}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\newlength\yearposx
\makeatletter
\def\blfootnote{\gdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}
\makeatother

\definecolor{lightgrey}{RGB}{245,245,245}

% slide numbering
\setbeamertemplate{sidebar right}{}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
    \hfill\usebeamertemplate***{navigation symbols}
    \hspace{1cm}\insertframenumber{}/\inserttotalframenumber}

% define title page

% begin document
\begin{document}


    

\frame{
    \frametitle{a}
    %till 2000

    \begin{center}
      \makebox[0pt]{%
\scalebox{0.7}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance=1.5 cm and 0.8cm,
ar/.style={->,>=latex,thick},
mynode/.style={
  draw,
  line width=1pt,
  text width=3cm,
  minimum height= 1 cm,
  align=center
  }
]

\node[mynode,text width=3cm, fill=lightgrey] (c1) at (0,0) {Diagnosed};
\node[mynode,text width=3.5cm, fill=lightgrey, below=1cm of c1] (c2) {First-line regimen \\[1cm]$  $};
\node[mynode,text width=3.5cm, fill=lightgrey, below=1cm of c2] (c3) {AAAA + AABB (CCCC) \\[1cm]$  $};

\node[align=center,text width=3cm,left=2cm of c2] (c2_3) {First-line \\ blbla};
\node[align=center,text width=3cm,left=2cm of c3] (c3_3) {Second-line \\ blbla};
\node[draw,align=center,text width=18cm,below left =1cm and -11cm of c3] (text1) {\textbf{aaa}: Very long long long text 1 \hspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{aaa}: Very long long long text 2\hspace{0.5cm}
\textbf{aaa}: Very long long long text 3};

\draw[->,thick] (c1) -- (c2);
\draw[->,thick] (c2) -- (c3);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{center}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try `\setsansfont{...}` instead of `\setmainfont{...}`, since the default in `beamer` is sans.

Comment: Thank you Thérèse, it works.